# Rtools not working in command prompt

Tags: r, command-prompt

First off, I'm unfortunately a windows user.  So downloading Rtools and being able to use it from the command prompt is a bit of a pain.  However, I figured it out.  And everything worked fine.  Just recently, however, I have not been able to run R from the command prompt using the R command.  This did work at one point.  However, now when I execute the command R in the command prompt R opens but when I type some R code (q(), matrix(1:4,2,2), etc...) and hit enter nothing happens.  This is very bizarre.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Does anyone know what is wrong?

One last thing.  I have tested the following R CMDs, INSTALL, SHLIB, build, check.  They all work fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try R --vanilla . Perhaps you're loading a workspace which is too large for your RAM.

Comment: If anyone has this problem in the future.  Josh W. comments, while a good idea, did not help.  What did work was working through Cygwin.